# When to use performblock for coredata operations?

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperation

I have a subclass of NSOperation which i use to sync coredata and cloud kit. The subclass has it's own privatequeue context with main context as it parent. I had a confusion on when to use the perform block with the private context. Do i have to use it for every fetch, save, accessing NSMangedObject ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you're working with a private context, you have to use performBlock for every operation.

A relevant link:
[Core Data Programming Guide: Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html).

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/0x73/CKSIncrementalStore/blob/master/CKSIncrementalStore/CKSIncrementalStore.swift)

This is what i am using, instead of using it as a incremental store am just using the logic the author here has not used performblock anywhere. Am i missing anything.

Comment: @user3519594, I believe, the author of CKSIncrementalStore is missing something. His/her code will look like it works until it breaks down. MOCs are not thread-safe. Private MOCs are intended to accessed only from the private thread that they manage themselves. And you can add work to that thread using `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait`. If you access a private MOC without using those methods, it might look like it works, but it will break down sooner or later.

Comment: @user3519594, take a look here: [Core Data Programming Guide: Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html).

Comment: thanks. I searched but everything is in parts so was not able to understand on how to handle the coredata concurrency thing when used like this.

Comment: Also, I have my database in app groups. So it may happen that the application and the extension will be using the same db at a particular time. The application has two context when sync is going on (Main - Child context) and extension will have its own main context on diff process. What care should i take so that the data do not get corrupted.

Comment: @user3519594, thanks for accepting the answer! Unfortunately, I haven't worked with app extensions yet, and I couldn't find a well ready-made article on the topic. I believe, you should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: is it fine if am nesting performblock calls like this :
code childMOC.performblockandwait({ childMOC.save() parentMOC.performblockandwait({parentmoc.save()
})})

Comment: @user3519594, yes, this is actually the way to do it. You might even go for `performBlock` instead of `performBlockAndWait` for saving, but it depends on the situation (whether or not you need the data to be available in the parent MOC right after the method that calls `performBlock` exits).

Comment: Okay so nested block to save child and then parent is fine :)

Comment: @user3519594, yup)